Why does a PSU not turn on with SATA SSD plugged in, but it acts very problematically without it?
I have a HX1200 modular PSU that normally has a few HDDs plugged into a single SATA power cable. I recently attempted to plug in a 4tb SSD with another (aftermarket) SATA power cable, but it would cause the PSU to not turn on. Upon removing the SSD, the computer would power on but it started behaving very weird and very slow.
At first it would not display anything at all, but after messing around with the GPU and it's power cables it eventually booted up but was then extremely slow on boot and in the desktop experience. I started troubleshooting and here's what I did:

Unplugged all other non-OS drives
CMOS reset
GPU (3080) driver reinstall (with DDU)
Checked on all connectors (all seated well)
Switched SATA ports on PSU and motherboard
Switched between HDMI/DP cables
SFC scan (corrupt files were found and replaced)
HDD health check (good health)

I do not notice any unusual sounds coming from the PSU nor any smells.

is the (aftermarket) SATA power cable compatible with your power supply modular connection? Aftermarket cables for modular PSU's are risky! As for your issues without this cable connected, it's unlikely to do with the PSU, unless the cable has damaged the PSU of course

It's not Corsair branded, which is the scary part. Is it possible that it somehow shorted the PSU leading to it not proving enough wattage to spin up the OS HDD? How would you go about testing this type of thing?

How much amperage is the rail rated for that the 4th SSD was plugged into, and have you verified the max amperage of all components on that rail don't exceed what the rail is rated for? If that checks out, disconnect all cables from the PSU except the power for the motherboard, fans, and boot drive (disconnect all other drives), the GPU as well if the CPU doesn't have integrated graphics, then power the system on. If it boots normally, shutdown, plug components in one by one until you find where the rail or cable issue exists; if it doesn't boot normally, try a known good PSU to test.

I assume it would not surpass the amperage rating of that rail because it was just the OS drive plugged in and it was still super slow. I don't it'd be normal for a single HDD to go over the limit. Anyway, I was testing system speed by mostly using the desktop and whatnot to feel the extreme slow, if I disconnected the HDD and just had BIOS, wouldn't it be quite difficult to discern slowdowns? Thanks for reply.

"Has a few HDDs plugged into a single SATA power cable?" - How many exactly are they? Why are you not connecting each HDD to it's own SATA power cable? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment. "I recently attempted to plug in a 4tb SSD with another (aftermarket) SATA power cable, but it would cause the PSU to not turn on." - I am going to case the cable was NOT compatible with your PSU.

@hx1200dude Have you left the PSU unplugged for a minute or so to reset the PCB? All the PSUs I've had do a PCB reset after ~15s without power, so I'm assuming it's standard. I would also check out the troubleshooting section in the manual - PSUs are extremely simple circuits with very basic PCBs that don't have a lot of components (even a a power brick is often more complex), so if basic troubleshooting doesn't result in anything, I would have a multimeter next to me while I called the PSU OEM's tech support to determine if the PSU has hardware damage.

(Cont'd...) @hx1200dude It should also be said coincidence doesn't equal correlation, so it's equally possible this has nothing to do with the PSU - contacting the PSU OEM's tech support will rule the PSU in or out, as will trying a known good PSU.

@Ramhound it's just like a daisy chained standard SATA cable. One connector in the PSU and 4 SATA connectors coming out of it.

@JW0914 How would the OEM determine if the PSU was faulty? Other than the PSU, what would you say it could possibly be? Note that the task manager displays all the right components with low usage of all resources, but the system is still very slow.

@hx1200dude - That’s no difference to adding splitter cables in serial. It doesn’t mean your PSU is capable of powering 4 HDDs off a single SATA power connector.

@Ramhound considering it came with the PSU, I think it's safe to assume that it is capable of the task.

@hx1200dude - Except it's not working and the SATA cable didn't actually come with the PSU.

@JW0914 - I have always used individual SATA power cables to connect multiple SATA devices. I wouldn’t connect more than, a couple devices, to a single SATA power connector on a PSU for a multiple of reasons. The corrupt files in this case is suspicious.

@Ramhound The connector itself doesn't dictate what it can and cannot power, that is determined by the internal 12V/5V rail for the circuit that connector is on, with the only requirement being the maximum amperage for all connected devices on each rail must be lower than the rated amperage for the rail (IIRC, mechanical HDDs have a max amperage of ~2A/per), which will be listed in the PSUs manual (for example, my server powers 4HDDs off a single connector x3). The connector itself has no bearing, except with GPUs due to the heat that can melt some connectors.

@hx1200dude The PSU OEM likely has voltage and resistance values to test for, hence the multimeter. Another thing you'll want to verify is the max amperage of all devices connected to the rail that circuit is on, as exceeding it can cause the system to run sluggish - what would eventually occur if that's the case is once amperage is needed by a component that exceeds the rail's current limit, the PSU auto powers off due to the over-current/over-voltage. Realtime monitoring of the voltage and amperage with a multimeter: back probe the wire through the wire end of the connector.

@JW0914 it turns out it was a BD PROCHOT trigger causing the CPU to get throttled no matter what, and because it's a 12th gen MSI motherboard, it's not possible to disable that, even while the CPU is chilling at 30 C.

@Ramhound check out above.

@hx1200dude - Why? It seems you figured it out. You apparently have a defective motherboard, if the sensor, is triggering this processor state. This should work regardless if the feature is locked within UEFI.  How you apply it since you are using Windows is the more difficult problem to solve.

@Ramhound No program to disable it worked, no option in the BIOS either, I was thinking about modifying the BIOS to unlock it, but considering it had an active warranty, I just sent it in for warranty.
